# Linux: Removed apache2 but webserver still working

Tags: linux

I have a Node+Express web-server, I'd like for it to listen on port 80 but it's already taken. I tried removing apache2 but it still is there. When I browse it I get the "default web page".

How can I fully remove it and have the port 80 free to use?

I'm running Debian 6.0 x86

Comment: It doesn't sound very removed. How did you attempt to remove it?

Comment: apt-get remove apache2 && apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've removed the package without shutting down the server first, execute:

```
sudo killall -9 httpd
```

If that still doesn't kill it, have a look at what's really using port 80 by doing:

```
netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 80
```

Find out what the server is that's using port 80 and stop/kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of stopping the apache webserver? (i.e. `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`)
Which method did you use to remove apache2? using dpkg/apt-get?

You could use `sudo netstat -l4np` to see which process is listening on port 80

Answer (score 0):

apt-get purge apache2

This command would remove apache2 and would also remove apache2 config files too. Try also stopping apache2 service if you don't want to remove it by the command /etc/init.d/apache2 stop.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

You could also try 'sudo service apache2 stop && sudo apt-get purge apache2' .
'sudo service apache2 stop' will stop apache2 deamon 'sudo apt-get purge apache2' will remove configuration files.